# The child views of the my parent ViewGroup remains unchanged and gets displayed in my new inflated layout at the bottom

Tags: android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater, custom-lists

### Inflation using Array Adapter - The inflated layout does not fill my full screen.

The views present in the parent View Group get displayed at the bottom of my newly inflated layout. The inflation is not fitting full screen and causing display issues as in the image. Code is working fine but i am having problem with my Display. Please suggest possible solution. The parent XML is also an inflated layout list(Array Adapter).

### Note

- The layout is properly inflated by setting attachRoot=false
  (Inflater.inflate(R.layout.chapterlayout, parent, false)).
- Cannot process ViewGroup from ArrayAdapter , so unable to remove the parent views.

INFLATED XML LAYOUT

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/my_background"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ENo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:text="1."
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:text="My Text"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/EE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Text"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

PARENT XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/my_background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#0000FF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/my_background">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA CODE

```java
public class MyChapterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MyChapterAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super (context, R.layout.main, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

static class ViewHolder { 
    TextView ENo; 
    TextView EA; 
    TextView EE;    
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder; 
    if (convertView == null) { 
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)   
getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.chapterlayout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(); 
        holder.ENo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ENo); 
        holder.EA = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.EA); 
        holder.EE = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.EE); 
        convertView.setTag(holder); 
   } else { 
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
   } 

   reDesignLayout(position,  holder);
   return convertView; 

}

private void reDesignLayout(int position, ViewHolder h) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String chapSplit[] =values[position].split("##");

       h.ENo.setText(chapSplit[0]+". "); 
       h.EA.setText(chapSplit[1]); 
       h.EE.setText(chapSplit[2]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to reduce your code to a minimal size that reproduces the error. Others may find it easier to help you if you do that.

Comment: The code works fine and is the minimal part of it to understand. i was not able to attach an image as am iam new in this site... If you can help then i can explain it

Comment: On uploading images see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Thank you for the link but they say , I require a minimum of 10 reputation for uploading images in my query.

Comment: You need one more upvote to get 10 rep :) . It also says you can link from external source. Not sure if you need rep for that.

Comment: :) thanks once again , let me try for the other uploading options

Comment: One last thing. You may want to add the [android] tag, which has more followers. Also, if you don't get any answers in a reasonable time keep editing your question, because this bumps it and makes it more visible.